# Rspec Failure - NameError: uninitialized constant Faker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, factory-bot

I'm facing this Failures: in Rspec - with Mongodb as database and devise for user management. Couldn't understand whats the issue.

with this command

> bundle exec rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb

```
      FFFF

Failures:

  1) User 
     Failure/Error: email { Faker::Internet.email }

     NameError:
       uninitialized constant Faker
     # ./spec/factories/users.rb:3:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User 
     Failure/Error: email { Faker::Internet.email }

     NameError:
       uninitialized constant Faker
     # ./spec/factories/users.rb:3:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) User 
     Failure/Error: email { Faker::Internet.email }

     NameError:
       uninitialized constant Faker
     # ./spec/factories/users.rb:3:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) User 
     Failure/Error: email { Faker::Internet.email }

     NameError:
       uninitialized constant Faker
     # ./spec/factories/users.rb:3:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00478 seconds (files took 2.1 seconds to load)
4 examples, 4 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:23 # User 
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:24 # User 
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:25 # User 
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:26 # User
```

with **/spec/models/user_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'


describe User do
    before { @user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)}

    subject { @user }

    it { should respond_to(:email) }
    it { should respond_to(:password) }
    it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
    it { should be_valid }
end
```

and **spec/factories/users.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    password "12345678"
    password_confirmation "12345678"
  end
end
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
# gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
# gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'mongoid', '~> 5.1.0'

#Api gems
gem 'active_model_serializers'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
  gem 'ffaker'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  gem "rspec-rails"
end

gem "devise"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NameError: uninitialized constant Faker

You have [***`ffaker`***](https://github.com/ffaker/ffaker) gem in your application which is ***refactored version*** of [***`faker`***](https://github.com/stympy/faker). So you need to use `FFaker` instead of `Faker`.

```
email { FFaker::Internet.email }
```

Comment: do you know since when this Faker has been deprecated.